# Group overlapping arrays

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

I have a list of arrrays that I want to put into groups of overlapping values. My instinct is to use itertools.groupby but I'm not sure how to make it work.

Some sample data:

```
a = np.array(range(10))
b = np.array(range(90,100))
c = np.array(range(50,60))
d = np.array(range(8,15))
e = np.array(range(55,80))
```

I want to end up with three groups of overlapping (or non-contiguous) arrays:

```
groups = [[a,d],[b],[c,e]]
```

Can I use itertools.groupby to do this?

```
for k,g in itertools.groupby([a,b,c,d,e], lambda x: SOMETHING?):
    groups.append(list(g))
```

But I'm not sure what to sort and group by. Any suggestions using this or any other method? Thanks!

UPDATE:

Thanks @abarnert for the solution below. You're right that it's not a huge number of arrays so iterating brute force works fine. I also did it with some clunky list comprehensions:

```
arrays, groups, idx = [a,b,c,d,e], [], []
for N,X in enumerate(arrays):
  if N not in idx:
    group, idx = [X], idx+[N]
    for n,x in enumerate(arrays):
      if n not in idx and any(np.where(np.logical_and(X<x[-1],X>x[0]))[0]): group.append(x), idx.append(n)
    groups.append(group)
```

Comment: Efficient interval sorting is actually an open research problem; is a quadratic solution good enough here? (For 5 intervals, it obviously is…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your list of ranges is small enough, you can just do this by brute force: check each range against each other range for overlap, "merging" them and starting the loop over every time you find one.

This is a bit clumsy to write with numpy arrays, so let's use (Python 3) range objects just to get the idea across:

```
def merge(x, y):
    return range(min(x.start, y.start), max(x.stop, y.stop))

def overlap(x, y):
    return x.start in y or y.start in x

groups = {a: {a}, b: {b}, c: {c}, d: {d}, e: {e}}

while True:
    for key, value in groups.items():
        for otherkey, othervalue in groups.items():
            if key is otherkey:
                continue
            if overlap(key, otherkey):
                del groups[otherkey]
                del groups[key]
                groups[merge(key, otherkey)] = value | othervalue
                break
        else:
            continue
        break
    else:
        break
```

This is obviously a wasteful algorithm, but considering that you have few enough objects to assign them each to a variable, who cares? It should be dead easy to understand, and that's probably more important here.